# Webmail Servidor Linux

Tags: php, linux, email

Estou a desenvolver uma plataforma e vou ter algumas contas de email dessa plataforma.

Como tal gostaria de poder utilizá-las pela web directamente na plataforma, como por exemplo: [www.webmail.exemplo.com](http://#).

O servidor que estou a utilizar é linux. Sabem se há algum template ou algum serviço que possa utilizar?

Answer (score 2):

Vc pode usar o Postfix http://www.postfix.org/
Ele é um servidor de e-mail, vc pode editar praticamente tudo nele.